# How to delay catch function in angularjs during routing to a page?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-service

I'm using $rootscope and two other service inside a service to update the data based on the current car. CarsService helps with car selection and DataSelection point to the folder that keeps the data. When no car is in the car list user should be directed to thank page.

Here is the error: "Sometimes the processes between services takes long and no car detected. so user directed to thank page." How could I delay the .catch without affecting the total performance?

```
      function DataSelection($rootScope, CarsService) {
        var self = this;

        function load() {
          self.carslist = [];
          return CarsService
            .getCars()
            .then(function (carslist) {
              self.carslist = carslist;
            })
            .then(CarsService.getCurrent)
            .then(function (data) {
              self.currentCarIndex = data.index;
              $rootScope.currentCarIndex = data.index;
              self.car = data.current;
            })
            .catch(function () {
              console.log('There is no car left, this should be disabled!');
              location.assign('/#/thank');
            });
        }

        self.loaded = load();

        self.updateCars = function () {
          return CarsService
            .gotoNext()
            .then(function (data) {
              self.currentCarIndex = data.index;
              $rootScope.currentCarIndex = data.index;
              self.car = data.current;
            })
            .catch(function () {
              console.log('There is no car left, this should be disabled!');
              location.assign('/#/thank');
            });
        };

        self.datalinks = function () {
          return self
            .loaded
            .then(function () {
              if (!self.car) {
                location.assign('/#/thank');
              }
              var folderName = self.car.toLowerCase();
              var jsonName = self.car.toLowerCase() + '-data.json';
              var jsonIntroName = self.car.toLowerCase() + '.json';
              var pictureB = '' + 'assets/' + self.car.toLowerCase() + '/' + self.car.toLowerCase() + '_b.jpg' + '';
              var pictureL = '' + 'assets/' + self.car.toLowerCase() + '/' + self.car.toLowerCase() + '_l.jpg' + '';

              return {
                folderName: folderName,
                jsonName: jsonName,
                jsonIntroName: jsonIntroName,
                pictureB: pictureB,
                pictureL: pictureL
              };
            });
        };
      }
```

Comment: The overall logic must be horribly wrong. The "processes between services" are either synchronous, in which case timing shouldn't be an issue, or asynchronous, in which case only a deliberate or unexpected `throw` will cause your catch clause to fire. Logically, when "processes between services takes long", the only way you would end up in the catch clause is for some sort of timeout to cause a `throw` to occur. If that's the case, then you need to catch/handle the timeout condition differently, and possibly elsewhere in your source. Or maybe you can shed further light on what's going on?

Comment: users are directed to thank page at three points inside DataSelection. Inside function load(), self.updateCars() and self.datalinks(). I think that throw happens inside the load.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe instead of catch I have to put other criteria.

Comment: I expect that .catch() is the correct thing to do but you may need to branch within the catch handler depending on which particular error was thrown. Test `error.message`.